# how to add response data to $scope object to use in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-http

Hello all i was trying to get response from `$http.get` method and append it to `$scope` object but it was stating undefined. After some research and referencing found the way to assign the data to object. But now facing issue with assigning and using in in view with `ng-repeat`.

Request all to please guide me on it.

JS:

```
var self = $scope;
self.localnews = {};

$scope.nearme = function($scope) {

    var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lon = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    var request = $http.get("functions/functions.php?activity=getlocalnews&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon).then(function (response) {
         self = response; 
        return self;
    });
   request.then(function (data) {
        self.localnews= (data.data)
        console.log(self.localnews);
   });

}
```

HTML View:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in ---what goes here??---" class="span12" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;margin:0;position:relative;">
```

Updated:

```
    var self = $scope;
self.localnews = {};

$scope.nearme = function($scope) {

    var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lon = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    var request = $http.get("functions/functions.php?activity=getlocalnews&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon).then(function (response) {
         self.localnews = response.data; 
        return self.localnews;
    });
   request.then(function (data) {
        self.localnews = (data);
       console.log(self.localnews);
   });

}
```

In view : appctrl is ctrl name.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in appctrl.localnews" class="span12" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;margin:0;position:relative;">
```

Comment: Why you did this `self = response;`?

Comment: simply use `self.localnews = response.data;` instead of `self = response;`. Your HTML would need `ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.localnews"` (I think you are using controllerAs syntax, so refer to its scope instead of `$ctrl`)

Comment: unable to assign it with view  please help with same.Please find the updated code

Comment: Have you updated your HTML?

Comment: Sorry kaustubh sir missed the updated HTML part

Comment: @SantoshUpadhayay, are you using controllerAs syntax?

Comment: no i am directly using controller name in ng-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are using `controllerAs` syntax, use this**

```
var self = this;
self.localnews = {};

$scope.nearme = function($scope) {

    var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lon = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    var request = $http.get("functions/functions.php?activity=getlocalnews&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon).then(function (response) {
         self.localnews = response.data; 
    });

}
```

**In HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="appctrl as app">
    <div ng-repeat="post in app.localnews" class="span12" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;margin:0;position:relative;">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**If you are not using `ControllerAs` syntax:**

```
$scope.localnews = {};

$scope.nearme = function($scope) {

    var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lon = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    var request = $http.get("functions/functions.php?activity=getlocalnews&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon).then(function (response) {
         $scope.localnews = response.data; 
    });

}
```

**In HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="appctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in localnews" class="span12" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;margin:0;position:relative;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Santosh Upadhayay, have you checked my answer? any more help needed?

Comment: Glad to help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
$scope.nearme = function() {
    var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
    var lon = localStorage.getItem('lon');
    $http.get("functions/functions.php?activity=getlocalnews&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon).then(function (response) {
         $scope.localnews = response.data; 
         console.log($scope.localnews);
    });
};
```

then use ng-repeat like this

```
<div ng-repeat="post in localnews" class="span12" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;margin:0;position:relative;">
```

where localnews must be an array.